# How to stop Finder window from disappearing during drag and drop from Chrome?

Tags: finder, google-chrome

While downloading files, I want to drag them from the bottom download bar in Chrome, the Finder disappears behind the Chrome window when I try to drag and drop the file. Is there a way to lock the Finder window so that it stays in front of the Chrome window when I drag and drop. I was able to do this before I updated Google Chrome to the latest version so it might be a software bug on their end.

Comment: In the latest Chrome (69.0.3497.100) download settings are found at: Chrome > Preferences > Advanced > Downloads. I set mine to go to my Desktop: `/Users/my_user_name/Desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Chrome Downloads history is here

chrome://downloads/

the actual download is already on your mac in the specified folder.

To specify where to download from Chrome, go to settings > Downloads.

The bar at the bottom of the Chrome window is FYI only, not the place where the downloads reside.

The downloads are already on you Mac and you do not have to drag them to the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac, you can hold down the command key while drag&dropping from the downloads bar to keep the finder window on top.
I believe this was indeed the default behavior earlier and was changed at some point.